# My own Improvised compiler error

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, x86-64, nasm

I am building a subset-of-C Compiler in C# on Linux using Monodevelop.
My compiler reads text from a file and outputs to assembly.
Now I would first have to note that the problem I get is not a C# problem, but an assembly misunderstanding. I am using nasm assembler and gcc linker.
Here is the outputed assembly:

```
extern printf
extern strcpy
extern systemsame
extern readinput
extern getdest
section .text
global main
jmp main_over
main:
push rax
mov rax, 0
mov rax, 1
mov byte [a], al
pop rax
push rax
mov rax, 0
mov rax, 0
mov byte [b], al
pop rax
IF_STATEMENT_0:
cmp byte [a] , 1
jne IF_STATEMENT_0_over
mov rdi, QUOTE_0
mov rax, 0
call printf
ret
main_over: 
IF_STATEMENT_1:
cmp byte [a] , 0
jne IF_STATEMENT_1_over
mov rdi, QUOTE_1
mov rax, 0
call printf
ret
IF_STATEMENT_1_over: 
IF_STATEMENT_2:
cmp byte [a] , b
jne IF_STATEMENT_2_over
mov rdi, QUOTE_2
mov rax, 0
call printf
ret
IF_STATEMENT_2_over: 
IF_STATEMENT_3:
cmp byte [a], 0
je IF_STATEMENT_3
mov rdi, QUOTE_3
mov rax, 0
call printf
ret
IF_STATEMENT_3_over: 
IF_STATEMENT_4:
cmp byte [b], 0
je IF_STATEMENT_4
mov rdi, QUOTE_4
mov rax, 0
call printf
ret
IF_STATEMENT_4_over: 
ret
IF_STATEMENT_0_over: 
section .bss
a: resb 1
b: resb 1
tempbyte: resb 20
tempword: resw 20
tempdword: resd 20

section .data

;Passon extra bit from parsing state;;;
QUOTE_0: db "a is 1!", 0
QUOTE_1: db "a is 0!", 0
QUOTE_2: db "a is b!", 0
QUOTE_3: db "a is true!", 0
QUOTE_4: db "b is true!", 0
```

I compile this with nasm assembler and get **NO** Errors and **NO** Warnings.
I then get an object code (`.o`) file and link it with another **Working** (tested) object code file (which has the definitions for `systemsame()`, `readinput()`, and `getdest()`)
using gcc. I get the following strange error:

```
In function `IF_STATEMENT_1_over':
outout.asm:(.text+0x71): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_8 against `.bss'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: by the way sorry if my assembly code is unreadable in some places. This is due to the fact that my compiler is very far from perfect.

Comment: You write "another working object file", but just because both object files are legal by themselves does not mean they will play well together - read about [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) for more information. Not saying this is the cause of the issue here, just a comment.

Comment: It worked with previous versions of my 'Compiler' so the object is definitely legal

Comment: What I mean is, it has nothing to do with "legality"; the object files need to use the same ABI, too.

Comment: but it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that the error is likely to be `cmp byte [a] , b` since that is just after the label mentioned in the error message, and involves symbols defined in `.bss`, the section mentioned in the error message. The instruction itself looks suspicious to me, but the exact error isn't quite clear: perhaps the address of `b` is being used as an immediate, which would involve its truncation to 8 bits.

Double check that this is in fact the translation that you want. I suspect that you should be loading the value at `b` into a spare register and then using that as the second operand to `cmp`.

As a side note, you should use "local" labels for basic blocks internal to a function. Otherwise the assembler will waste time and space creating useless relocations. Usually this involves nothing more than prefixing those labels in some way. For example for GNU `as` it is `.L` - consult the manual of the assembler that you are targeting.